# Showing UILabel in UIWindow gets delayed in iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-6-plus

I have this code:

```
UIWindow* window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(UIWindow *win1, UIWindow *win2) {
        return win1.windowLevel - win2.windowLevel;
    }] lastObject];

    NSString* labelText = self.message;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]};

    CGRect rect = [labelText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(500.0f, MAXFLOAT)
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                       attributes:attributes
                                          context:nil];
    CGSize labelSize = rect.size;

    float viewWidth = labelSize.width+20;

    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((window.bounds.size.width-viewWidth)/2, window.bounds.size.height/2.5, viewWidth, 30)];
    label.alpha = 0;
    [window addSubview:label];

    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor =[UIColor blackColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = labelText;
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 15;
    label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{

        label.alpha = 0.9;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:self.duration options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            label.alpha = 0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [label removeFromSuperview];
        }];
    }];
```

In iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, the UILabel shows immediately after executing previous code but in iPhone 6 plus, it takes up to 5 seconds before showing in the screen, this is very strange, what's wrong in this code?

Comment: Is this code executing on the main thread?

Comment: @MichaelL yes, on main thread